# How to get last working date in DAX Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I have a calendar table as below

[Calendar Table](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yuckvf575ix1gjd/PBII.png?dl=0)

I want to get the last working date based on DayType. Here H=Holiday and W=Working Day

So, I create a measure as follows

LastWorkingDay = CALCULATE(LASTDATE(RollingCalender_LookUp[Date]), FILTER(RollingCalender_LookUp,RollingCalender_LookUp[DayType]="W"))

But it did not give me the correct result. The measure gives me Blank.
Can you please tell me the mistake I did here.
Thanks.

Comment: Such a simple measure should work just fine. Is the data type of column RollingCalender_LookUp[Date]  Date? Maybe it's the wrong data type, and so lastdate can't use it.

Comment: The data type of column RollingCalender_LookUp[Date]  is Date. I solve the the problem with the following code.

LastWorkingDay = CALCULATE(MAX(RollingCalender_LookUp[Date]), FILTER(ALL(RollingCalender_LookUp),RollingCalender_LookUp[DayType]="W"))

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the the problem with the following code.

LastWorkingDay = CALCULATE(MAX(RollingCalender_LookUp[Date]), FILTER(ALL(RollingCalender_LookUp),RollingCalender_LookUp[DayType]="W"))

Thanks.